# Can't serialize object with URI

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion, android-room, converters

I have this class:

```
data class ProjectFile(val uri: Uri, val name: String)
```

and I have another class that contains it and is saved in Room database.

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
@Entity(tableName = "projects")
data class Project(
  @PrimaryKey
  @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
  var id: String = "",
  @ColumnInfo(name = "uid")
  var uid: String? = "",
  @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
  var name: String = "",
  @ColumnInfo(name = "businessId")
  var businessId: String?,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "image")
  var image: String?,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "tasks")
  var tasks: List<Task> = ArrayList(),
  @ColumnInfo(name = "managers")
  var managers: List<Person> = listOf(),
  @ColumnInfo(name = "files")
  var files: List<ProjectsViewModel.ProjectFile> = listOf()
```

and I keep getting this error:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private android.net.Uri() with no args**

it can't convert the object "ProjectFile" to string in the Converters file.
what can I do to fix it?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of the `Uri` class is private and it's an abstract class. It tries to create a new object for the `Uri` class using `Reflection API`(We can't create an object for abstract class). So better to change the type of uri object into `String` instead of `Uri`.

```
data class ProjectFile(val uri: String, val name: String)
```